# GRASS 7.2.1 Installation in Windows 10 StartUp Problem

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I have attempted to use the GRASS plugin v.clean in QGIS 2.18.15 to sort out a messy polygon layer.
When I tried to run the algorithm. An error message popped up;

[image: Error Executing Algorithm]

I attempted to open the existing GRASS software I had on my computer. This window pops up.

How do you install this software?

[image: Adding Location for GRASS software]

Comment: If that window pops up you have installed it. Try creating a location and GRASS will start. See https://grass.osgeo.org/documentation/first-time-users/ . I dont know why it does not work from QGIS though.

Comment: I am unable to add new location using the link you have provided. A blank error message keep popping up every time I try to add a location

Comment: Your GRASS GIS installation works fine (the second window is the stand-alone startup). The issue is that your QGIS installation does not find GRASS GIS. Which QGIS version do you use? Please edit the posting with that information, thanks.

Comment: remember to activate the plugin, from the plugins dialog; you may see the process options without the plugin being active